# iOS Place a View on a TableViewCell when cell is in focus

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

In a VC I have a tableView with custom Cell "ChartListCell". When the user is on any particular cell I want to open a view with 2 buttons in it on top of the cell and let user click on any button and appropriate action be taken for that cell. What would be the best way to implement this feature ? I am stuck at :-

1. Event to find cell/row is selected.
2. Place the view at the cells' position - so it stays on top of the cell.
3. Create the view with 2 btns - would be better to create it programmatically so events can be mentioned in the same VC only or to create a xib would be better option ?
4. Hide the view again when selection is lost.

UPDATE :-
   So I tap the cell, the view (like below with 2 buttons) appears. If I scroll the table, the view stays on the cell. Once I tap an option on the new view , or tap on another cell or somewhere outside it disappears.

**UPDATE :-** 
I created a xib file and in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` am trying to show the view, but it's not appearing.

```
        // Get the SELECTED CELL
    ChartListCell *cell = (ChartListCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"ABOUT TO SHOW VOV");

    NSArray *visitorOptView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VisitorsOptionsView" owner:self options:Nil];
    VisitorsOptionsView *vov = [visitorOptView objectAtIndex:0];
    vov.frame = cell.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:vov];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:vov];
```

Nothing appears. Where am I going wrong ? To give the same location as of the cell, I tried `vov.frame = cell.frame` , but I think I may be wrong at that step. What else should be at that place ???

What would be the best methods to implement the above ? Can you please help me guide out. Any help is highly appreciated.

Below image shows what I am looking to meet up the design :-
[image]

Comment: How do you determine what cell has focus?  Are you talking about when `didSelect` and `didDeselect` are called?

Comment: What do you mean with "cell is in focus" and "When the user is on any particular cell"? Are you talking about a control being first responder?

Comment: Welp, two of us making different but equally good assumptions about what "focus" means, so I guess for now I'm voting to close this question as unclear.  Please update the question and make it very clear what you mean, perhaps including screenshots of what the tableview looks like, as well as a better explanation of these temporary buttons you want to add to the screen.

Comment: @nhgrif, have added a screen shot and more clarification on focus term and what I am looking for.

Comment: So I tap the cell, the view appears.  If I scroll the table, the view stays on the cell.  Once I tap an option on the new view, it disappears.  Is this a sufficient explanation of the intended behavior?

Comment: Either tap an option on new view or somewhere else or some other cell, then view disappears from current cell & shows on other cell if is to be.

Comment: Can you please edit this very clear/concise explanation of the intended behavior into the question?

Comment: @nhgrif, you mean didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, right.

Comment: Yes.  And `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this demo project for you:http://goo.gl/Y6GFmj , you can download it

You can add the view into your table cell instead of your view. You need to subclass your table view cell and add a property to hold the overlay view.

```
    @interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
    @property (weak, nonatomic) UIView * overlayView;
    @end
```

Note that the overlay view should be a weak property, because the cell's view will have the strong reference to it, just like an IBOutlet.

You need to add another property in your table view controller to hold the last selected index path, so that when you select a new row, you can remove the overlay view in the old one.

```
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath * lastSelectedRow;
```

Use the following function to remove the overlay view from a cell

```
    - (void)removeViewInCellOfIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (!indexPath)
        return;

        MyTableViewCell * cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell.overlayView)
        {
            [cell.overlayView removeFromSuperview];
        }

    }
```

Now you can deal with the selection:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // deselecte the row
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

        // remove the overlay view from the last selected row
        [self removeViewInCellOfIndexPath:self.lastSelectedRow];

        // add overlay view to this row
        MyTableViewCell * cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        // note the origin of the frame is (0, 0) since you are adding itto the cell instead of the table view
        UIView * view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:view];

        // remember this view and this indexpath
        cell.overlayView = view;
        self.lastSelectedRow = indexPath;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sen. Your demo, Geet's answer and referring some other sites, all helped me solve my problem and could get thru it.

Answer (score 1):

I had done something similar to this, What I did was while creating my custom cell I had placed another view at the bottom which contained the two buttons, make the two buttons as IBOutlets of their classes.

When I load it in my table view with the usual method in CellForROwAtIndexpath I defined as following...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)couchTableSource:(CBLUITableSource*)source
                cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

      NSString *cellid=@"Cell";

            CustomTableCell* cell=(CustomTableCell*)[_Mytableview     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];

            if(cell==nil)
                {
                NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];
                }

    [cell.firstButton addTarget:self action:@selector(firstButtonClicked:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.secondButton addTarget:self action:@selector(SecondButtonClicked:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

I maintained a global integer flag  as SelectedIndex and used it  as follows

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath I have done something Like this..

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
        {
        selectedIndex = -1;
        [_Mytableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        return;
        }

    //First we check if a cell is already expanded.
    //If it is we want to minimize make sure it is reloaded to minimize it back
    if(selectedIndex >= 0)
        {
        NSIndexPath *previousPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
        [_Mytableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:previousPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }

    //Finally set the selected index to the new selection and reload it to expand
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;

    [_Mytableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


}
```

also and the most important step  in heightForRowAtIndexPath

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if(indexPath.row == selectedIndex)
        {

        return  (return the actual size of the cell, Including the view with two buttons);
        }
    else
        {
        return (return the size of cell -(the size of view containing the two buttons));
        }
}
```

In viewWillAppear make Sure to assign this so that the cell would be normal whenever the is presented

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

  selectedIndex=-1;

   [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Geet. Your answer, Sen's answer and referring some other sites, all helped me solve my problem and could get thru it.